# (Java 7 NIO.2) custom name for the watch service thread

Tags: java, nio, java-7

Using nio.2 in Java 7, when you create a watch service like that:

```
WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
```

Then, a background thread is started, polling for file system events within an infinite loop. The name of this thread is "Thread-n" which is a bit of a nuisance when investigating thread dumps or during profiling sessions.

Can we change the name of that thread?

Comment: Is there a reason you are worrying about the WatchService being a problem?

Comment: There is no reason. That's why when investigating a thread dump I would like to immediately be able to put the watch service thread aside after recognizing its name.

Comment: How about doing the opposite, ignore it if you don't recognize it?

Comment: I am going to not recognize this comment ;)

Comment: Good question. If you drill down the API, you can see that a `WatchService` is an interface, while a `FileSystem`'s `.newWatchService` is abstract. I haven't delved into the code yet, but at first glance it does not seem possible to change the thread name... Unless you provide your own `FileSystem` implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the implementation, it does not seem possible directly. If you don't mind a little hack, you can find the thread and rename it.

Something like (//TODO: put error checks in place):

```
Set<Thread> threadsBefore = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
WatchService ws = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

//I don't need to wait here on my machine but YMMV

Set<Thread> threadsAfter = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
threadsAfter.removeAll(threadsBefore);
Thread wsThread = threadsAfter.toArray(new Thread[1])[0];

System.out.println("wsThread = " + wsThread);

wsThread.setName("WatchService Thread");

Set<Thread> justChecking = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
System.out.println("justChecking = " + justChecking);
```

Comment: I like the spirit ;)

But it's a bit dirty even for me. In a heavily multi-threaded environment, there may be more than one thread added/removed in the time between stack collections...

Comment: @AntoineCHAMBILLE Since each WatchService implementation is JDK/OS specific, and they don't give access to their thread, I don't think you can do much better I'm afraid...